# WSL2 and PySide6

Tags: python, pyside, wsl-2, pyside6

I am trying to run a simple PySide6 app on WSL2

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ . ./venv/bin/activate
$ pip install PySide6
$ sudo apt install libopengl0 libegl1
```

My code:

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
                                                     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    label = QLabel("Hello World", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    label.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run, I got the error

```
$ export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0\n
$ python main.py
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

[1]    2557 abort      python main.py
```

Is it possible to run PySide applications using WSL2? If yes, how?

Comment: try install xvfb `sudo apt install xvfb` and then:  `xvfb-run python main.py`

Answer (score 2):

1, X Server https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242

i) install https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

ii) `` export DISPLAY="`grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | sed 's/nameserver //'`:0" ``

iii) run `xev` to test [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx6aG.png)

iv)include the command ii at the end of the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file:

2,  `sudo apt install pyside2-tools libopengl-dev`

3, run `python3 xxx.py`
it worked but still has some problem. output:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-dev'
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: yeah this did not work for me :(